# How does `ip netns exec` command create mount namespace?

Tags: linux, namespaces, mount

How does `ip netns exec` command create a mount namespace and prevent the changes from being propagated to other mount namespaces?

Following is the from the man page of `ip-netns`:

> For applications that are aware of network namespaces, the convention
>   is to look for global network configuration files first in
>   /etc/netns/NAME/ then in /etc/. For example, if you want a different
>   version of /etc/resolv.conf for a network namespace used to isolate
>   your vpn you would name it /etc/netns/myvpn/resolv.conf.
>
> ip netns exec automates handling of this configuration, file
>   convention for network namespace unaware applications, by creating a
>   mount namespace and bind mounting all of the per network namespace
>   configure files into their traditional location in /etc.

But, how does it manage the bind mount being visible only in that particular namespace?

Let me show an example.
In one terminal, I create a network namespace ns3, and create a specific resolv.conf for ns3.

```
# ip netns add ns3
# mkdir /etc/netns/ns3
# echo "ns3 conf" > /etc/netns/ns3/resolv.conf
# ip netns exec ns3 sleep 36000
```

Now in another terminal, I examine the /etc/resolv.conf.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
default conf
```

The change made by the bind mount is not reflected here.
The change is visible, only if i enter the mount namespace created by the `ip netns` command.

```
# lsns | grep mnt
4026533472 mnt        1 13016 root             sleep 36000
# nsenter -m -t 13016
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
ns3 conf
```

So all works as expected.

Now let me try to do this directly with `unshare` command, instead of using `ip netns exec`.

I create a namespace again. With `unshare`, I am creating a mount namespace and doing the bind mount inside that mount namespace. I assume this is what `ip netns exec` command internally does.

```
# ip netns add ns4
# mkdir /etc/netns/ns4
# echo "ns4 conf" > /etc/netns/ns4/resolv.conf
# unshare -m --propagation unchanged /bin/bash
# mount --bind /etc/netns/ns4/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

But this time when I check from another terminal, the changes have been propagated back which is not desired.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
ns4 conf
```

So what is the additional step that `ip netns exec` does which prevent this propagation of changes? I assume it is related to the usage `make-shared` or `make-slave` flags, but couldn't figure out exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that if I use `# unshare -m --propagation slave /bin/bash`, the propagation is prevented.

`ip netns exec` command seems to be running `mount --make-rslave /` after `unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)` is done.
i.e, after new mount namespace is created, / is mounted as slave in that namespace.

Comment: There is a related answer at Unix & Linux that uses `strace` to analyze what `ip netns exec` is doing: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471214/249381